# How to convert date('H:i A d-M-Y') format in php

Tags: php, date

I want to convert date format in php.

I have a variable `$date = '05-27-2016 15:30'`. I want to convert it into `'3:30 PM 27-May-2016'`.

I try this one `date('H:i A d-M-Y',strtotime($date))` but it gives wrong result.

How do I do that?

Comment: Invalid time format: [Check this](https://3v4l.org/PUmVV)

Comment: this link should help you http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: When using strtotime(), a `-` separator is treated as UK/European date format `dd-mm-yyyy` and there is no month 27, so strtotime() will fail.... `/` for US format,`-` for European format

Comment: also check this: [https://3v4l.org/8Xi7n](https://3v4l.org/8Xi7n)

Answer (score 2):

Use createFromFormat function

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i', '05-27-2016 15:30');
echo $date->format('h:i A d-M-Y'); // 3:30 PM 27-May-2016
```

Comment: Sir, I think you convert the day to month..., I make this as first comment, did you see?

Comment: i dont think that 27 is month :)

Comment: @splash58 wow Amazing :o :D

Comment: Hi @splash58, it gives me `15:30 PM 27-May-2016` but I want `3:30 PM 27-May-2016`.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari [READ THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and see if you can figure out how to change hours from 24hr to 12hr clock yourself

Comment: thanks, you saved my time.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari change to lower case `h`. And dont forget to read markBaker's link :)

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

As i Commented out both the format, You need to change the format before changing final for final format.

> If you need `3` at `03`, just use `g` at `h`.

**General:** [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/PUmVV)

```
$date = '27-05-2016 15:30';

echo date('h:i A d-M-Y', strtotime($date)); //03:30 PM 27-May-2016
```

Or ,

**using Object Oriented:** [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/8Xi7n)

```
$date = '05-27-2016 15:30';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i', $date);

echo $date->format('h:i A d-M-Y');
```